# Vim marks and US international keyboard

Tags: linux, vim, keyboard

I use a US-international keyboard so that pressing <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> produces "á" while on insert mode.

However, I would like to access a mark named **a** by pressing <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> under normal mode. That doesn't work and as a workaround I have to press <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>space</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>.

Is there a solution? I mean, can vim even *see* that I pressed the <kbd>'</kbd> key or the whole dead-key mechanism is invisible to vim so that it only gets a keystroke when <kbd>a</kbd> is typed afterward (I'm on Linux)?

In that last case I could, of course, remap "à" to "'a" on normal mode. But that wouldn't work with every key, I mean, pressing <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> produce no text output at all on my current keyboard layout.

Answer (score 1):

Your hunch is right: The dead keys are handled by the operating system outside of Vim, and Vim only sees the result.

You could remap the `'` command to a different key, but there are few unused ones left.

In case you're mostly editing in Vim (and you probably should, as it is such a superior experience), you don't need the US International layout at all: Vim provides its own input method for special characters, called *digraphs*. Inside Vim, you can enter the `á` character by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>'</kbd>, <kbd>a</kbd>.